# Parse data from JavaScript of retrieved page

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, open-uri, ruby-2.1

I'm retrieving a web page with OpenURI:

```
require 'open-uri'
page = open('http://www.example.com').read.scrub
```

Now I'd like to parse the values of the attributes `playerurl`, `playerdata` and `pageurl` of the retrieved page. They appear in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
..
..
  PlayerWatchdog.init({
      'playerurl': 'http://cdn.static.de/now/player.swf?ts=2011354353',
      'playerdata': 'http://www.example.com/player',
      'pageurl': 'http://www.example.com?test=2',
      });
..
..
</script>
```

What's the smartest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the three JS attributes". Is there an embeded script that you want to parse? Or are these inside HTML elements?

Comment: It's a script-tag inside the html-page itself. By attributes I mean the values of 'playerurl', 'playerdata' and 'pageurl'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has no built-in javascript parsing capabilities. You can use a regexp, though this will be rather sensitive to the formatting of the page (for example this will break if the page starts using double quotes for strings):

```
playerurl = page[/'playerurl':\s*'([^']*)'/, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an HTML parser, such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), to take apart the HTML document, and quickly find the `<script>` tag you're after. The content inside a `<script>` tag is text, so Nokogiri's `text` method will return that. Then it's a matter of selectively retrieving the lines you want, which can be done by a simple regular expression:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      PlayerWatchdog.init({
          'playerurl': 'http://cdn.static.de/now/player.swf?ts=2011354353',
          'playerdata': 'http://www.example.com/player',
          'pageurl': 'http://www.example.com?test=2',
          });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
EOT

script_text = doc.at('script').text 
playerurl, playerdata, pageurl = %w[
  playerurl
  playerdata
  pageurl
].map{ |i| script_text[/'#{ i }': '([^']+')/, 1] }

playerurl # => "http://cdn.static.de/now/player.swf?ts=2011354353'"
playerdata # => "http://www.example.com/player'"
pageurl # => "http://www.example.com?test=2'"
```

[`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#at-instance_method) returns the first matching `<script>` [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) instance. Depending on the HTML you might not want the first matching `<script>`. You can use `search` instead, which will return a [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), similar to an array of Nodes, and then grab a particular element from the NodeSet, or, instead of using a CSS selector, you can use XPath which will let you easily specify a particular occurrence of the tag desired.

Once the tag is found, `text` returns its contents, and the task moves from Nokogiri to using a pattern to find what is desired. `/'#{ i }': '([^']+')/` is a simple pattern that looks for a word, passed in in `i` followed by `: '` then capture everything up to the next `'`. That pattern is passed to String's [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.